# Invariant subspaces of the identity map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> How many invariant subspaces does the identity map on $R^2$ have?

My attempt:

1. {0}, which coincides with the kernel.
2. $R^2$, which coincides with the image and eigenspace.

Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *any* vector space, the identity map sends every vector to itself, and hence every subspace to itself.

Comment: So, as there are infinite number of 1 dimensional subspaces of $R^2$, the identity map has infinite number of subspaces. Did I understand your idea?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. The only linear transformations with this property, by the way, are the dilations.

Answer (score 0):

Take any non-zero $\vec x\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $\lVert\vec x\rVert=1$ and $x_1,x_2>0.$

What can you say about the subspace spanned by $\vec x$? How many of these subspaces are there? How many subspaces does $\Bbb R^2$ have?

Less specifically, suppose $W$ is *any* subspace of $\Bbb R^2.$ What can you say about $W$?